# Can I preserve the state of my React component while it's offscreen but not update it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app has several related screens. Only one of them is shown at a time. When the parent context changes (at the top level, above all the screens), each screen has to do some expensive work.

So that I don't slow down the current screen, I unmount the currently hidden screens when they're not visible. Notionally, there's a multiplexer sitting at the top level:

```
const page1 = currentScreen === 'page1' ? (
    <Screen {...page1config} />
  ) : (
    null
  )

const page1 = currentScreen === 'page2' ? (
    <Screen {...page2config} />
  ) : (
    null
  )

return (
  <div>
    {page1}
    {page2}
  </div>
)
```

But each page also has local state. With this solution, that state disappears when I switch to the other page.

When I switch to page2, is there a way I can keep the local state on page1 but *not* actually render anything on that page?

Another way to phrase this question would be: what can I do to mimic the (allegedly upcoming) [React Offscreen component](https://react.dev/blog/2022/06/15/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-june-2022#offscreen) until it's available?

Comment: Did you try memoize pages with useMemo() hook?  It's the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer with the given information. It might be trivial, it might be practically impossible.

1. If you just want to avoid the expensive procedures, I'd suggest to pass a flag like `isActive`, and suppress the procedures accordingly.
2. You might consider separating the state from the visual representation, if appropriate.
3. If you really want to mimic the "offscreen" feature, I'd say that is probably at least hard, if not impossible, because there is (probably) sophisticated internal optimization, which is not supposed be dealt with by the users of React.
4. If you want to display the components, but with less priority, you might build something to "throttle" the expensive process. But that depends a lot on the actual process, and might be not trivial.